# What's the best way to refresh a group header in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

If I have a [custom Tabulator groupHeader](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/group) function that includes a custom calculation such as:

```
noteCount = getNoteCount();
noteButton.innerText = `Notes (${noteCount})`;
```

What is the best way to refresh that header when note count changes? In this case my noteCount variable is independent of the table data.

I am currently using the setGroupBy function after updating the number of notes:

```
tableName.setGroupBy("groupField");
```

This works, but seems heavy-handed as it resets the grouping for the whole table. It also resets the scroll position to the top of the table. I would rather target just a single group header, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to redraw just the group header as they are only generated when rows are added or removed from the group.

you could try calling the ***redraw*** function on the table:

```js
table.redraw();
```

Comment: Thanks Oli, redraw does work although I still need to scroll to the row afterwards. Am I right in thinking that in general redraw is less expensive than setGroupBy and should have fewer side effects and therefore redraw would be considered best practice for my requirement?

Comment: Redraw only redraws the visible data. SetGroupBy rebuilds all the group's on the table them redraws the data. You could try redraw without the true option

Comment: Thanks Oli, `table.redraw()` looks like the best option: it refreshes the header without the need to scroll the row afterwards. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.